# C# XMLReader - Multiple child collections failing Validation with XSD schema

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have a supplied XSD. I do not know enough about XSD to begin modifying it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Dataset">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Person">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="PayrollNumber" type="String16" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" />
              <xs:element name="Surname" type="String50" maxOccurs="1" />
              <xs:element name="Name" type="String50" maxOccurs="1" />
              <xs:element name="StreetAddress" type="String50" maxOccurs="1" />
              <xs:element name="Suburb" type="String20" maxOccurs="1" />
              <xs:element name="Skills">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Skill" type="String16" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="HomePhone" type="String14" maxOccurs="1" />
              <xs:element name="MobilePhone" type="String14" maxOccurs="1" />
              <xs:element name="PagerNumber" type="String14" maxOccurs="1" />
              <xs:element name="Email" type="String80" maxOccurs="1" />
              <xs:element name="RecordType" type="RecordType" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:simpleType name="String16">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="16" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="String50">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="50" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="String20">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="20" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="String30">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="30" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="String14">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="14" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="String80">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="80" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="RecordType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="A" />
      <xs:enumeration value="E" />
      <xs:enumeration value="D" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

I have the following XML.

```
<Dataset>
  <Person>
    <PayrollNumber>1234567</PayrollNumber>
    <Surname>Denson</Surname>
    <Name>John-Jaime-Winston Junior</Name>
    <StreetAddress>Level 5, City Central Tower 2, 121 King William St</StreetAddress>
    <Suburb>Mitcham</Suburb>
    <Skills>
      <Skill>Skill1</Skill>
      <Skill>Skill2</Skill>
    </Skills>
    <HomePhone>08 8888 8888</HomePhone>
    <MobilePhone>041 888 999</MobilePhone>
    <PagerNumber>111111</PagerNumber>
    <Email>curly@stooge.com</Email>
    <RecordType>A</RecordType>
  </Person>
</Dataset>
```

The NET file validator works fine with XMLReader.

However if I introduce multiple Person records - ie. a collection the validation fails with
Validation error: The element 'Dataset' has invalid child element 'Person'. 0 0

How can I modify my XSD?

Comment: If you post XML or code, **ALWAYS** highlight those lines in your editor window and use the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar (fifth from the left) to format those lines as code/XML. Then and only then will they show up nicely and be syntax highlighted and all !

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your XSD right now defines a sequence of exactly one element `Person` inside the data set.

You can easily change that by changing this line in your XSD:

```
    <xs:element name="Person">
```

to

```
    <xs:element name="Person" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
```

If no `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` values are given, they default to 1 - so you get a minimum and a maximum of exactly one `Person` inside your dataset.

Change those values to something that makes sense to you, e.g. `minOccurs="1"`, `maxOccurs="10"` or use the `maxOccurs="unbounded"` for any number of occurences (no limit).